# Why is Cypress click working so inconsistently?

Tags: cypress

We are in the process of moving Selenium tests to Cypress. Cypress worked out wonderfully but tests became very flaky. They are failing randomly. Most often culprit seems to be click().
The click(it is clicking on the delete icon) is not working as expected and it proceeds to the next step and fails on assertion checking if the element is deleted.

We have tried cy.get().click({force: true}) or cy.get().trigger('click'). We have tried putting cy.wait before and after click. It will work but also randomly fails.

Below is just one example, clicks failing in many places. It works half of the times and fails the other half:

```
cy.contains("div", "item1").should("exist").and("be.visible");
cy.get('[data-test-id="UnassignItem_1"]')
    .should("exist")
    .should("be.visible")
    .click({ force: true });
cy.contains("div", "item1").should("not.exist");

<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>            
                <td class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                    <div class="item-container " data-test-id="item1">item1</div>
                    <i class="icon-close-bold-sm unassign-item" data-test-id="UnassignItem_1"></i>
                </td>                       
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

There are many examples like above. Most often it is failing in different parts of the applicaiton where click is involved.

what else can I do to make this reliable?

Comment: Is there any api calls after click? If so, you'd need to add wait() for it.

Comment: It could be your app is not ready by the time of the click. What is the error returned in your situations?